# JavaScript nested objects

Tags: javascript, object, nested

I have object with structure like:

```
{
    Name: "Test",
    OperationProperties.Prop1: "Val1",
    OperationProperties.Prop2: "Val2",
    OperationProperties.Prop3: "Val3"
}
```

but I need to represent it as:

```
{
    Name: "Test",
    OperationProperties: {
                            Prop1: "Val1",
                            Prop2: "Val2",
                            Prop3: "Val3"
                         }
}
```

Please tell me, is there any way to do it except implementation of manual casting?

Comment: I don't understand. Your first structure isn't valid JavaScript. Is it some serialized format?

Comment: Yes, it is deserialized structure, received from server

Comment: Oh, ok. If it has been deserialized into JavaScript objects, then I'm afraid there's no automatic way to turn your `OperationProperties.PropX` into a sub-object. You'll have to test the properties manually. curious though, is it starting out as valid JSON data? And if so, are you using `JSON.parse()` to parse it?

Comment: I already tried such approach, and unfortunately source is not valid json string(actually it is a JavaScript object with complicated property names).

Comment: Object property names may have dots in them, but they may only be accessed like `obj['property.name']`. Note that `a.b.c` is not the same as `a['b.c']`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find any ways how to do it except writing code to perform this cast manually.

```
function cast(source, prefix) {
    var result = {};

    for (var property in source){
        if(property.startsWith(prefix)){
            var propertyNameWithoutPrefix = property.replace(prefix + '.');
            result[prefix][propertyNameWithoutPrefix] = source[property];
        }else {
            result[property] = source[property]
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```